# What type of clustering would occur if one of the functions in double hashing is constant?

Tags: hashing, clustering

If the hash is calculated as h(k, i) = (h1(k) + i*h2(k)) mod |T|

What would happen if h1(k) or h2(k) is constant? Would that produce primary or secondary clustering? I think both would produce secondary clustering and I don't see how it would cause primary clustering because I feel the i multiplying h2(k) prevents the formation of a big cluster, but I get different opinions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $h_2$ is constant we have [open adressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) with linear probing. Usually the step size equals $1$, but here it is another constant. It has both primary and secundary clustering. For the primary cluster, not all keys are next to one another, but rather a constant $h_2$ places apart.

When $h_1$ is constant, I would not call this hashing at all, as the keys are not distributed over the address space at all. Whether it has clustering seems then irrelevant in my opinion.